# Spring RestTemplate and Proxy Auth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, proxy

I'm trying to do REST calls with Spring. As I understand, the right way to go is using `RestTemplate`(?). Problem is, I'm behind a proxy.

This is my code right now:

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host, 3128);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, address);
factory.setProxy(proxy);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

It seems to work, but I need to authenticate at the proxy, but how is this done? The `Proxy` type as well as the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` type don't seem to handle credentials. Without credentials, I'm getting just 407...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After quite a few different options I settled on The below code due to the ability to set the proxy for the RestTemplate at creation so I could refactor it into a separate method.  Just to note it also has an additional dependency so keep that in mind.

```java
private RestTemplate createRestTemplate() throws Exception {
    final String username = "myusername";
    final String password = "myPass";
    final String proxyUrl = "proxy.nyc.bigtower.com";
    final int port = 8080;

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials( 
        new AuthScope(proxyUrl, port), 
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
    );

    HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, port);
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

    clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).disableCookieManagement();

    HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

//Dependencies I used.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What if I'm using Spring 3.0.1? I don't have the class HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Comment: This solution is not backwards compatible to Spring 3 you will need to create the request factory differently.   I am not familiar with Spring 3 so yo will have to do some research.  I strongly recommend using Spring 4 as Spring 5 is already on the way.

Comment: I know but unfortunately, on my project, is not possible upgrade a newer version . I turned around using an unauthenticated proxy and using SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory (Spring 3.0.5) instead of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(Since Spring 3.1)

Answer (score 8):

the code below worked for me.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials( new AuthScope("proxyHost", "proxyPort"), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("proxyUser", "proxyPass") );
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

clientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
clientBuilder.setProxy(new HttpHost("proxyHost", "proxyPort"));
clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
clientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());

CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
factory.setHttpClient(client);

restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your proxy require basic auth, you can simply set the HTTP header `Proxy-Authorization` to handle authentication:

```java
final SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
final InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host, 3128);
final Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, address);
factory.setProxy(proxy);

final String username = "Aladdin";
final String password = "open sesame";

final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
    .requestFactory(() -> factory)
    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.PROXY_AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ':' + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
    .build();
```

You don't need to use an additional dependency for that.