# Resource Access Exception with Spring RestTemplate onTomcat 8 (requiring proxy config) Running on Eclipse MARS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, proxy

I have an application that uses spring to the calling rest services. Specifically, the RestTemplate class. Right before I make the call to:

```
restTemplate.execute(
                url, 
                method, 
                new JSONRequestCallback(headerParams), 
                new JSONResponseExtractor(containerType, cls));
```

method, I check the value url in the call. I quite literally can copy and paste the value of that url (lets call it http://myHost.net:8081) into a browser in the same network domain as my tomcat 8 (the web container I am using in eclipse), and the service response is successfully returned from the browser. However, the execute method throws an exception upon return:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: myHost.net; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: myHost.net
```

Now, the web service I am calling is on the internet while my dev environment is not. To address, we opened an appropriate port in our firewall and I can successfully access the service endpoint from a browser (as indicated above) by properly configuring the proxy settings on the browser. Similarly, from my Tomcat 8 configuration within eclipse, I have added the following launch configuration VM arguments:

```
-Dhttp.proxySet=true
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myHost.net
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

but as I have indicated above, I still get the unknown host exception.

By the way, I did see a similar issue here ([Spring RestTemplate and Proxy Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273236/spring-resttemplate-and-proxy-auth)) but that required a coding solution in the spring code. I was hoping for a configuration solution as our system will not have the proxy issue in the operational environement.

I am hoping someone might have some ideas as to either what I might be doing wrong, and/or how I might be able to better diagnose my problem. Thank you!