# Eureka not discovering service by name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

I'm running simple eureka service discovery example as given in the link below :

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-cloud/rest-template-load-balancer.html

I observed that while I am running this example on my home wifi/personal laptop this runs fine whereas while it runs on my office workstation on the corporate network, the resttemplate in unable to resolve the services by their name. (get 407 proxy unauthorized)

I can see that both the services are getting successfully registered on Eureka.

What might be stopping the Eureka server to work correctly on the corporate network?

P.S.: By following the answer and making the resttemplate and proxy aware results in 503 services unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your rest template to be proxy aware. You can find how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273236/spring-resttemplate-and-proxy-auth)

Comment: thanks , but now I am getting  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for hello-service" ,where as both services are UP as per eureka server.

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar then check your Eureka service discovery and your corporate proxies over there. In my case, Our DevOps team did that after I have explored that.

Comment: I am running service discovery on my local system as an spring boot app, would like to recommend some thing in this case