# How to solve "I/O error on POST request" from restTemplate

Tags: java, resttemplate

higuys!

I have a problem with restTemplate right now.
There are two requests while using this restTemplate.
First one is simple like login.
Other one(the problem) is sending quite long text with post body.

If I send the request on Postman, it works well.
I think the length of string might be the problem, but I'm not sure.

Request Parameter is

```
{
    "name"  : "test",
    "age"   : 28,
    "gender" : 2,
    "type"  : 1,
    "store" : "test2",
    "imgLen" : 2876,
    "img" : "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"

}
```

Source code is

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            factory.setConnectTimeout(timeout); 
            factory.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

            //body 
            MultiValueMap<String, String> reqBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            int i=0;
            if(reqParam != null) {
                for (Object key : reqParam.keySet()) {
                    i++;
                    String keyString = key.toString();
                    reqBody.add(keyString, reqParam.getString(keyString));
                }
            }
            //header 
            HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
            header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            if(reqHeader != null) {
                for (Object key : reqHeader.keySet()) {
                    String keyString = key.toString();
                    String value = reqHeader.getString(keyString);
                    header.set(keyString, value);
                }
            }
            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(reqBody, header);

            UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(host+reqUri).build();


            log.append("\n---------[ BI-API -> Face Manager API ]-------------------------------------------------------------");
            log.append("\nRequest URL       : ").append(uri);
            log.append("\nRequest URI       : ").append(reqUri);
            log.append("\nmethod            : ").append(method);
            log.append("\nRequest Body      : ").append(ObjectUtil.getAllParameters(reqParam));

//            ResponseEntity<Map> resultMap = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, Map.class);
            ResponseEntity<Map> resultMap = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri.toString(), entity, Map.class);
```

The error is

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://{ip}:{port}/face/emp": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:468)
    at com.lguplus.bi.api.faceMgr.FaceMgrApi.callAPI(FaceMgrApi.java:116)
    at com.lguplus.bi.api.service.user.UserService.sendFaceInfo(UserService.java:549)
    at com.lguplus.bi.api.controller.user.UserController.requestCreateUser(UserController.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.lguplus.bi.api.filter.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    ... 58 more
```

The log is

```
021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [MainClientExec.java]execute(255) : Executing request POST /face/emp HTTP/1.1
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [MainClientExec.java]execute(260) : Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [MainClientExec.java]execute(266) : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(124) : http-outgoing-0 >> POST /face/emp HTTP/1.1
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/json, application/*+json
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> api-key: eV1GXF5neW0fd2NlMDkzNDk0MGludGVsbGk=
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Charset: utf-8
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 2973
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: 172.16.2.36:5214
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_191)
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]onRequestSubmitted(127) : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /face/emp HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json, application/*+json[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "api-key: eV1GXF5neW0fd2NlMDkzNDk0MGludGVsbGk=[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Charset: utf-8[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 2973[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: 172.16.2.36:5214[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_191)[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(72) : http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(86) : http-outgoing-0 >> "{"id":["test"],"age":["28"],"gender":["1"],"store":["[0xea][0xb0][0x95][0xeb][0x82][0xa8][0xeb][0xa7][0xa4][0xec][0x9e][0xa5]"],"imgLen":["2816"],"img":["/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCABwAHADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDw6ZjIxYnk1BinnnpSbTTbGhuKTyyx4qUITVu3tCxHFS2NFQwlVzTNhrVuLQqnSqqxcVNyrFMrijbVt4cCotnNUmS0QYpQvrT2XBpuadxWDAxiun8IeI20m6WOQ/uzxzXL4peinHBqkyWj6Ggu47yFJojkEA0zxIc+D9X/AOvKX/0A1xXgHWWuIHtpDnbjFdl4iz/wh+sHP/LlL/6AaZB4ERg05RmjqKntYjNKFArNs2SJ7S1MhHFbtvZBQOKsWGmFVUla1fsoRaycjohAxbq1DIeKx1hAYjFdTKgORWNNbMkhOOKjmNOQoGAGqk9uVPArXMRHOKcbcSociqUiHA514iBUBXFa8tuUY56VTmt/StEzKUSnTSaldCOKhPFWjJo7n4eQlr99p6ivSPERJ8H6v/15y/8AoJrhPhrFnfIRypxXdeIv+RR1gf8ATpL/AOgmrMup4ORg8V1XhjSTcSCQrwK5y2i82dU98V6voGnC0sk45IrCTOyEBJLdLaPp0rn73UGDkKp4rr7i3EvBFZF1psQB+QfWuds6YxOV/tCQt0qdZTMvIqa4t4o3PApkJQuFFTcuxOturxdOaqTp5IOK2fJ2Q7qy5vnYg1SZLRg3TyMThTVMeZnla6CRIl6gVAyQN0xWikYuJiiHzGPFVLiExvjHU8V0a26ZyKp3tsDcRem4ZrSMjGcT0TwBp4g0nzmXHmCtrxG2PCusj/pzl/8AQTU+h26W+jRInTANVvEvHhbV/wDr0k/9BNb9Dle55m2kHTtbjQr8rHivT4F2WUZH90VzmtmKe/tpEHKtzXTQHdZIPauKUj2VTsV3nRQc9axNUvZWUiJDWnPCSxqnLGBnIrNmiicLdSXjTEsuBUliz+eM5reu7dXbhRTLXTwZc4pBYvSOPsfvisCWX94QK6K5hCQ49q5q4AWY0EuJRuYpnPDVB9mlUdSa2Y1UgZqXyFNVclxM62DAYaodTRjDuT7w6VqmEL0qFofNniTGQWANawZhUjoeieFXkl0SIv3UdaTxTx4X1X/r0k/9BNaOmWy22lwxLxgVn+Kxjwpqp/6dZP5GutbHnS+I52xt/Mu/Ln4YHgmuqtlCoE7Cq9zp8QmEq4DVagG1AOtcEtD3YyTQ24i4yKwrtWUn0rpWwRzWVfxqFPFZlHOSNzzU1vuLfKM1DOjFiAKlila2gbaPmpgTXUMvlkspxXPXUOGJrai1OV1dZlO33rn9Smd5T5fSgQkTENjNX0HGazLb5sE9a1EICUENkUhwaZCC13GB6g0sh5NWdGt2uNTi4yAea2pnPV2PS4F/0WL3UVj+LOPCmq/9ez/yrdC7IUT+6MVieLv+RT1T/r2f+Vdi2PMluaU9sH5FQouzg1fwT1qlN8j1y1Ynbh6r2YP0rNvFyDWgzjFUrj5q5j0EzDmCoSTUYjLjcSAKTUVmZ8Riq32TUmj+8AvoBTHcbdFFGA1Zk3l7T0zUtza3EYO8kmsqeGU9zTsS2Soyq3Bq2r5HWsuGCXeN1asUe1etIzbA8it/wfHv1BiRkYrnmbaCa7fwdZGK2adhgnpW9JHNWlZHTk7jxWF4uH/FJar/ANez/wAq3VA5rE8XD/ikNW/69n/lXZayPPb1NonNV7qMNGTVL/hJNC/6Denf+BSf40j+ItBKHOt6cfYXSH+tZyVy4SaYwSdVNMfBHFZ0+t6OWJTVrHH/AF8J/jUUev6V0Op2f/f9f8a4pxdz1YTVty28YLZIqUSFExjiqn9uaOf+YnZf+BCf40yXWtJKfLqdkf8Atuv+NTZl867lbUQsmTWG8I3c1o3Gqaa2cahan6TL/jWTNqNmGO27gP0kH+NVZicl3EdQnaofOwcZqGXUbY9LiI/8DFU3vYCeJo/++hQou5k5o2NOgbUNQjiXlc816va26WlpHCgxgc15HoOvWWl3vnTOrD2YV6NZ+L9EvQCdQtoSezygfzrrpRscdaVzbrF8Xf8AIn6t/wBez/yq4dc0f/oLWP8A4EJ/jWP4r1jS5vCmqRQ6jZySNbsFVJ1JJx2ANbM5EtT/2Q=="]}"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [Wire.java]wire(86) : http-outgoing-0 << "[read] I/O error: Connection reset"
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]close(79) : http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]shutdown(87) : http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [ConnectionHolder.java]abortConnection(128) : Connection discarded
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java]close(79) : http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java]releaseConnection(320) : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://ip:5214[total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://ip:5214/face/emp": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java]writeWithMessageConverters(268) : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-05-21 16:10:05 [DEBUG] [LogFormatUtils.java]traceDebug(91) : Writing [{}]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);

Comment: "Connection reset" may be a time out in the server. Do you have logs from the server?

Comment: @Julia5049 . I have same problem. Did you resolve problem?

Comment: @IlyaY, Nope. I gave up using restTemplate and used  java.net.URLConnection openConnection() instead.

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was with the proxy setup.
Configured by example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273236/spring-resttemplate-and-proxy-auth

Answer (score 1):

Hi Julia This quite feels like the protocol issue. The AWS is fully TLS 1.2 or higher supporting, but the client is not. The Rest Template if not configured otherwise, will start negotiation with TLS 1.0. You have to forcefully make the client to connect only with 1.2 or 1.3 protocol stacks.

```
 SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(null, null, null);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(context)
    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

Comment: Hi Zaur. Thank u for your answer. I tried as you sais, but doen't work for me. Tank you though!

Comment: Welcome Julia5049

Answer (score -2):

`I/O error on POST request for "http://{ip}:{port}/face/emp"`

It seems you do not set a valid host:port

Check your `host` and `reqUri`

```
UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(host+reqUri).build();
```

Comment: She should be sending a response obj via @Controller method...  She is already using Spring MVC. Why would she build a url from factory? Its already built into the framework... reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Thank you guys. I changed host and uri information for security. As I said other request to same server works fine. So I guess the uri is not the problem.