# Spring boot 3.2 RestClient proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

RestClient has arrived in Spring Boot 3.2. There are a lot of articles and guides online using the good old RestTemplate, not so much about the new arrival. Using the new RestClient, how can I set a proxy in order to make a call to an external IP?

An example where there would also be authentication at the proxy would be best.
Something like the solution given here for RestTemplate : [Spring RestTemplate and Proxy Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273236/spring-resttemplate-and-proxy-auth)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Exactly the same way as the `RestClient` uses the same infrastructure components as the `RestTemplate`.